# What kind of fruit is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

[image]
[image]
[image]

Just spotted this fruit while walking to school. It's the size of a small coin.The taste is almost sour and tangy and somewhat sweet (I only tried one of them and very little of it).  I admit, I've never seen it before. Does anyone know what this is?

Update: Location is two or three blocks north of UC Berkeley (Berkley, CA, USA).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: strawberry tree]

It's probably [*Arbutus unedo*, strawberry tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbutus_unedo). Native to Mediterranean region and some part of western Ireland.

Edit: I've just spot that you found it in California, so it's probably one of north american [*Arbutus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbutus) species, eg. [*Arbutus menziesii*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbutus_menziesii).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. Now I'll eat the rest of them without fearing dying.

Comment: @darksky I've never eaten this kind of fruits so please don't blame me nor the SE community if they appear not edible.

Comment: Yes it is Arbutus Unedo. We have several in the garden. In Spain it is called a Madroño. The fruits are edible, but they don't taste that great. They are not very sweet and can have a mushy texture. Use them to make jams.